# Does mesa driver works with EEVEE on Linux?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, drivers

I know that Cycles uses GPU for rendering and you need to have amdgpu-pro proprietary drivers installed and I can see my GPU (RX580) in options for OpenCL settings. However, AMD driver has some nasty issues with other software I use, so I wonder is default Mesa driver enough for EEVEE to be able to use my GPU (RX580)?

Answer (score 1):

I use the default AMDGPU drivers because I tried thrice and have still not been able to install AMDGPU Pro. Eevee works absolutely fine on Mesa with my RX 560. Even for Cycles, it's not essential to have OpenCL, you just have to use CPU render. I'm happily blendering on after I switched to Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I started using an eGPU (Razer Core X) with an RX 580 on my laptop (XPS 9370) with elementary OS 5.1. I used the PPA below to install the latest mesa drivers (20.3.1):

[https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa)

```
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.3.1 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.3.1 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.1 - kisak-mesa PPA
```

EEVEE works excellent. Of course, for me, it's a massive leap forward coming from an Intel UHD 620 :). But unfortunately, no Cycles GPU rendering.

I'm seriously considering buying an equivalent Nvidia card. I believe CUDA does work with my setup.

**UPDATE:**

In the meantime, I managed to make Cycles work using the proprietary drives from AMD. More about how to install them can be found here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/26197/can-i-use-an-egpu-with-elementary-os-and-if-so-how-do-i-set-it-up/26198